# Generic class method returning some value

Tags: java, generics

I am getting ClassCastException. I was following this answer but did not get it right.
[Cast Object to Generic Type for returning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524751/cast-object-to-generic-type-for-returning)
BubbleSort.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class BubbleSort<T extends Number> {

    public List<T> list;

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public BubbleSort() {
        list = new ArrayList<T>() {
        };
    }

    public void add(T obj) {
        list.add(obj);
    }

    public void sort() {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < list.size() - 1; j++) {
                if (list.get(j).intValue() > list.get(j + 1).intValue()) {
                    T swapElement = list.get(j);
                    list.set(j, list.get(j + 1));
                    list.set(j + 1, swapElement);
                }
            }
        }
    } 

    public <T> T getArray(Class<T> clazz){
        T[] returnArray = (T[]) list.toArray();
        return clazz.cast(returnArray);
}

}
```

MainPorgram.java

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;


public class MainProgram {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        BubbleSort<Integer> bubbleSort = new BubbleSort<>();
        bubbleSort.add(new Integer(1));
        bubbleSort.add(new Integer(2));
        bubbleSort.add(new Integer(6));
        bubbleSort.add(new Integer(5));
        bubbleSort.add(new Integer(4));
        bubbleSort.add(new Integer(3));
        Class<Integer[]> intArrayType = (Class<Integer[]>) Array.newInstance(Integer.TYPE, 0).getClass(); 
        Integer[] sortedArray = (Integer[]) bubbleSort.getArray(intArrayType);
        for(int i = 0 ; i < sortedArray.length; i++){
            System.out.println(sortedArray[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Console

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast
>   [Ljava.lang.Object; to [I     at java.lang.Class.cast(Unknown Source)     at
>   BubbleSort.getArray(BubbleSort.java:32)   at
>   MainProgram.main(MainProgram.java:15)

Comment: _"did not get it right"_ is insufficient. You are expected to post the stack trace and indicate which line in your program throws the exception.  Also tell us what you've done to troubleshoot the problem. Did you step through the code in your debugger?

Comment: There are so many things wrong here.

Comment: `(BubbleSort.java:32)` This means the error occurs on line 32 of BubbleSort.java. Which line is this?

Comment: I don't think that the conversion with arrays works quite as you hope - and why not change it a bit - just do something like this instead: `Integer[] sortedArray = bubbleSort.list.toArray(new Integer[bubbleSort.list.size()]);`
The problem is that the method getArray() always returns an array of objects, where the objects within that array is integer - however, you're expecting an array defined with Integer. Might be someone else may help you on how  you can fix generics, however I don't see how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues.

The main issue is that `list.toArray()` returns an `Object[]`, and you can't cast it to an array of a different type. You should use `<T> T[] toArray(T[] a)` to get an array of the correct type.

Another issue with your code was that your generic parameter declared in the method `<T> T getArray(Class<T> clazz)` hides the generic parameter of the same name declared in the class level (`class BubbleSort<T extends Number>`).

Here's a suggested fix that works :

```
public T[] getArray(Class<T> clazz) {
    return (T[]) list.toArray((T[])Array.newInstance (clazz, list.size()));
}

....

Integer[] sortedArray = bubbleSort.getArray(Integer.class);
```

Comment: Might as well pass in the list length. Also, the outer cast shouldn't be necessary in `getArray()`.

Comment: @Eran Thanks dude!! i got it

Answer (score 2):

There's quite a bit of confusion and mistaken assumptions in your code. Instead of detailing all of them (some have been covered in other answers), I'll suggest a working approach that's much simpler, if you're on Java 8:

```
public class BubbleSort<T extends Number> {

    public List<T> list;

    public BubbleSort() {
        list = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    //...

    public T[] getArray(IntFunction<T[]> arrayGenerator) {
        return list.stream().toArray(arrayGenerator);
    }
}

public class MainProgram {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        BubbleSort<Integer> bubbleSort = new BubbleSort<>();
        //...
        Integer[] sortedArray = bubbleSort.getArray(Integer[]::new);
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Cannot cast `[Ljava.lang.Object;` to `[I` at ...

The message may be confusing you. Here `[Ljava.lang.Object;` actually means the type `Object[]` and `[I` means `int[]`. These are Java **type signatures** which can be decoded according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/8066268/224671.

---

So the error message is complaining you are trying to cast an `Object[]` to an `int[]`. The only place where you referred to the `int` type is this line:

```
    Class<Integer[]> intArrayType = 
           (Class<Integer[]>) Array.newInstance(Integer.TYPE, 0).getClass();
```

The problem is you are using `Integer.TYPE` which returns the type of `int`, so the class you get will be `Class<int[]>`. To use the actual Integer class, write:

```
    Class<Integer[]> intArrayType = 
           (Class<Integer[]>) Array.newInstance(Integer.class, 0).getClass(); 
    //                                                  ^~~~~
```

(See [Difference between Integer.class and Integer.TYPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195424/difference-between-integer-class-and-integer-type) for the difference.)

Note that since you already know that you will deal with `Integer[]` class, you don't need to call `.getClass()`, just this is enough:

```
Class<Integer[]> intArrayType = Integer[].class;
```

But this is still wrong, e.g. in

```
public <T> T getArray(Class<T> clazz){
    T[] returnArray = (T[]) list.toArray();
```

you will be asserting to get an `Integer[][]` (and more problems which I'm not gonna go in detail)... See [@Eran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41713524/224671) for the proper fix.

Comment: You've only addressed part of the problem. It's still returning `Object[]`.

Comment: This will only change the error to `Cannot cast [Ljava.lang.Object; to [Ljava.lang.Integer;`

Comment: That last edit is incorrect. It's true that `T[]` would be `Integer[][]`, but because of type erasure the cast is ignored. The problem is on the next line, where `list.toArray()` [returns `Object[]`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray--), which can't be cast to `Integer[]`.